# SumIFS Excel multiple criteria

Tags: excel, sumifs

I would like to sum the costs according to origin-destination.
So for example trade between Africa and Asia costs A (amount), Africa and Middle-East B etc... the costs and destinations are on a different sheet.

I figure can use `SumIFS` to get the total costs, but so far no success to connect all the criteria.

Any suggestions?

```
       africa   Asia    Middle-East Europe  North America   South America   Oceania
africa  None     A          B        C       D               E             F
Asia    A        None       S        C       K               W             L
```

Comment: The data you provided doesn't look good here.  Do you mind to post a screenshot?

Comment: What's the criteria you want? And what data you would like to sum?

Comment: Lets say a plane goes from Asia to Africa and with that there will be a fix cost and additional cost of A. So sum of the cost is Fix cost + A ( cost depending on origin and destination).